# When Player collides with Wall it bounces him off and launches from wall to wall forward and i don't know how to fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller

Here is my code
and link to a video, where you can witness my "monster"
[text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuMyE.jpg)
Player and Walls have tags - Player, Wall

Collider with

```
None physical Material
Is Trigger - unchecked
Radius - 0.5
```

and Rididbody with

```
Mass - 1
Drag - 0 
AngularDrag = 0.05
Use Gravity = unchecked
Is Kinematic = unchecked
```

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool smoothTransition = false;
    public float transitionSpeed = 10f;
    public float transitionRotationSpeed = 500f;

    Vector3 targetGridPos;
    Vector3 prevTargetGridPos;
    Vector3 targetRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetGridPos = Vector3Int.RoundToInt(transform.position);
        Collider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        collider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            prevTargetGridPos = targetGridPos;

            Vector3 targetPosition = targetGridPos;

            if (targetRotation.y > 270f && targetRotation.y < 361f) targetRotation.y = 0f;
            if (targetRotation.y < 0f) targetRotation.y = 270f;

            if (!smoothTransition)
            {
                transform.position = targetPosition;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * transitionSpeed);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), Time.deltaTime * transitionRotationSpeed);
            }

            // Check for collisions with walls
            Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 0.4f);
            foreach (Collider hitCollider in hitColliders)
            {
                Debug.Log("Collided with " + hitCollider.gameObject.name);

                if (hitCollider.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
                {
                    targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos; // move the player back to their previous position
                    break;
                }
            }
            Vector3 nextStep = targetGridPos + 2 * transform.forward;
            Collider[] nextStepHitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(nextStep, 0.4f);
            foreach (Collider nextStepHitCollider in nextStepHitColliders)
            {
                if (nextStepHitCollider.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
                {
                    return; // don't update targetGridPos if the next step will collide with a wall
                }
            }
            targetGridPos = nextStep;
        }

        else
        {
            targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // Check if the collision is with a wall
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            // Move the player back to their previous position
            targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos;
        }
    }


    public void RotateLeft() { if (AtRest) targetRotation -= Vector3.up * 90f; }
    public void RotateRight() { if (AtRest) targetRotation += Vector3.up * 90f; }
    public void MoveForward() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos += 2 * transform.forward; }
    public void MoveBackward() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= 2 * transform.forward; }
    public void MoveLeft() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= transform.right; }
    public void MoveRight() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos += transform.right; }


    bool AtRest
    {
        get
        {


            if ((Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetGridPos) < 0.05f) &&
                (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation) < 0.05f))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to make player not able to move in the direction of wall if he will collide with him on next step(for example if player presses "A", and with this press he will collide with the wall, nothing will happend, but he will be able to move forward with "W" if next step is not colliding with the wall and so on.

When i launch game, it just bounces of into the void like in the video

Comment: your player seems to move without instrunctions, unless of course you do press keys in the video.  Surely you want a 4 point check and a yes/no for the points and if that key is pressed and way is clear then action else dont..

Comment: Do you slow down the speed, and change the direction the vector is pointing when the player would hit a wall? The player speed should probably change proportionally to how hard they try to walk into a wall.

Comment: in general when dealing with physics you shouldn't go through `Transform` at all! Rather move your object via the `Rigidbody` and use `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and `Rigidboy.MoveRotation` which takes all occuring collisions in between into account.

I would assume you moving via `Transform` makes the object be stuck inside the wall and is then pushed out of the wall by physics resulting in your being "launched"

Answer (score 0):

There is a second code variation, where i didn't break movement completly, but i can move towards the wall while pressing WASD and if i move in wall, player stumbles on it and bounces off, movement breakes afterwards.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool smoothTransition = false;
    public float transitionSpeed = 10f;
    public float transitionRotationSpeed = 500f;

    Vector3 targetGridPos;
    Vector3 prevTargetGridPos;
    Vector3 targetRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetGridPos = Vector3Int.RoundToInt(transform.position);
        Collider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        collider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (true) // here is an error?
        {
            prevTargetGridPos = targetGridPos;

            Vector3 targetPosition = targetGridPos;

            if (targetRotation.y > 270f && targetRotation.y < 361f) targetRotation.y = 0f;
            if (targetRotation.y < 0f) targetRotation.y = 270f;

            if (!smoothTransition)
            {
                transform.position = targetPosition;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * transitionSpeed);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), Time.deltaTime * transitionRotationSpeed);
            }

            // Check for collisions with walls
            Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 0.4f);
            foreach (Collider hitCollider in hitColliders)
            {
                Debug.Log("Collided with " + hitCollider.gameObject.name);

                if (hitCollider.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
                {
                    targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos; // move the player back to their previous position
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // Check if the collision is with a wall
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            // Move the player back to their previous position
            targetGridPos = prevTargetGridPos;
        }
    }


    public void RotateLeft() { if (AtRest) targetRotation -= Vector3.up * 90f; }
    public void RotateRight() { if (AtRest) targetRotation += Vector3.up * 90f; }
    public void MoveForward() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos += 2 * transform.forward; }
    public void MoveBackward() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= 2 * transform.forward; }
    public void MoveLeft() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= transform.right; }
    public void MoveRight() { if (AtRest) targetGridPos += transform.right; }


    bool AtRest
    {
        get
        {


            if ((Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetGridPos) < 0.05f) &&
                (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation) < 0.05f))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post amendments as answers. You can edit your question to include more code and information.